# Angular $watch issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I have a controller which uses a Factory to set up a list of items. In the template, every single items gets printed with an angular strap radiobutton component attached:

```
<ul class="list-group" 
    infinite-scroll="tags.load()" 
    infinite-scroll-disabled='tags.busy' 
    infinite-scroll-distance='1'>
        <li class="list-group-item" 
            ng-repeat="tag in tags.items">
               [[tag.tag]] 
               <span class="badge">[[tag.books.length]]</span>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" 
               ng-model="button.tagactions" 
               bs-radio-group>
            <label class="btn btn-success">
               <input type="radio" class="btn" 
                      value="approved-[[$index]]">
               Approve
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-danger">
               <input type="radio" class="btn" 
                      value="rejected-[[$index]]">
               Reject
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-info">
               <input type="radio" class="btn" 
                      value="new-[[$index]]">
               Restore
            </label>
          </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

In my controller I am setting up the factory, as well as a $watch on those radiobuttons:

```
  $scope.tags = new Tags($scope.button.tagfilter);


  $scope.$watch('button.tagactions', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log(oldValue)
      console.log(newValue)
      if(newValue != oldValue) {

          $scope.tags.changeTagStatus(newValue, function(test,val){

          });
      }
  });
```

And my Factory:

```
  tagApp.factory('Tags', function($http,$rootScope) {
  var Tags = function(state) {
    this.items = [];
    this.state = state;

  };

  Tags.prototype.changeTagStatus = function(val) {
      var val = val.split('-');
      var id = this.items[val[1]]._id;
      var path = ...;
      $http.post(path).success(function(data) {
          this.items.splice(val,1);
    }.bind(this));
  }

  Tags.prototype.load = function() {

    if (this.busy) return;
    this.busy = true;

    var path = '/api/rawtags/'+this.state+'/'+(this.items.length)+'/20/frequency';
    $http.get(path).success(function(data) {
        this.items = this.items.concat(data);
        this.busy = false;
    }.bind(this));
  };


  return Tags;
});
```

When now the tags.items list get updated by removing an item, something really strange happens with the $scope.$watch('button.tagactions'... functionality.

When I remove the first item, it works as it should: The tagactions function is called with the correct radiobutton value and the list in my browser updates with the first item missing.

When I then click on the first item again item (formerly the second item in the list), it seems that the values of the radiobuttons were not updated, as they are still reflecting the old status. So instead of the second item, the third is removed.

And when I click again on this item, I can track two calls on the tagactions watch, first registering a click with the correct radiobutton value, and then another one with the value from the very first list status before any updates were made.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.items.splice(id, 1);`?